# How to pair a Wear OS emulator to a companion app running in another emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, wear-os

Is this possible in the current version (Arctic Fox) of Android Studio but nothing that I have tried has worked? I've seen references to old procedures that are not supported.

If this is not possible, what approach do other developers use to solve simultaneous development of a watch face and a companion app?

Thanks,

John

Comment: I assume by the many questions on this that it is not possible to do this today.  So how do developers test new watch faces and companion apps?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/get-started/creating#pairing-assistant

> Note: Your phone must be running Android 11 or higher and have the Google Play Store installed to use the Wear OS emulator pairing assistant. This tool is only available in the Arctic Fox Canary 14 release.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you clarify what build this is in?  When I look at the Canary builds, the current one is shown as Chipmunk (2021.2.1) Canary 1.  Does this include the fix?

Comment: Yes, it should definitely be included there.

Comment: Was the pairing assistant removed from Android Studio Eel?  The option is missing from the UI in Eel Canary 1 & 2 (with find actions its seems to exist but is disabled always).  Same problem for me on both windows and mac.

Comment: It moved to the Device Manager tool window.  In the kebab menu for each emulator.